# complex nodejs url mapping

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I need help in url mapping in express.js  framework in nodejs.

```
router.get('/first/:second_param', function(res,req){
    //processing second_param and rendering a template,
res.render('first.html');
});

router.get('/first/:second_param/get_items', function(res,req){
    //again evaluating second_param and and responding accordingly
res.send(jsonData);
});
```

Is this kind of routing possible in Express 4.0?

*first.html* makes a ajax request at url **'./get_items'**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do it with Express 4.0.

Here is an example:

you need to install ejs and express: `npm install ejs express`

`app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/home/2');
});

app.get('/home/:itemId', function(req, res) {
  var itemId = req.params.itemId;
  console.log(itemId);
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/api/items/:itemId', function(req, res) {
  var itemId = req.params.itemId;
  console.log('item id: %s', itemId);
  res.json([{name: 'item1'}]);
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 8080');
});
```

---

`views/index.ejs` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <script>

                function responseGET() {
                  if(this.readyState !== 4 || this.status !== 200) return;
                  alert(this.responseText);
                }

                function getItems(URL) {
                  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  request.open('GET', URL, true);
                  request.onreadystatechange = responseGET.bind(request);
                  request.send(null);
                }

                function domReady() {
                  getItems('http://localhost:8080/api/items/1');
                }

                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domReady);
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically I am have a server which is serving an index.html when someone requests at `/home/:itemId` and also I am exposing another route for serving items `/api/items/:itemId`.

From the client side once the DOM is ready I am requesting to `/api/items/:itemId` some items which then are displayed in the index html.